# Tabbed or Tapped

Tags: etymology

I've heard the word "tapped" quite frequently for selecting a person for a job or title but I've recently seen "tabbed" used instead, mainly by sports writers. It just sounds wrong to me considering tab came from tabulate. I can't find any history of the use though. Anyone know when it became accepted?

Comment: Are you sure you heard correctly and could it be they were saying "tagged"?  I guess I'd need to see/hear an example of "tabbed" used in that way since it sounds so odd to me.

Comment: Well damned if you aren't right.  I found a number of recent examples when I Googled "tabbed" in quotes.  I'm sticking with that it sure sounds odd to me! :-)

Comment: Odd indeed.  Merriam-Webster doesn't list the verb form at all.  [OED does](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/tab), designating that use as "chiefly North American", but this North American doesn't recall ever seeing or hearing that usage.  Also, OED defines it as "Identify as being of a specified type or suitable for a specified position", as opposed to actually *selecting* whatever is tabbed.

Comment: See [Notes to Reviewers](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7913/142322)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[To tab](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tab):***

> - 9. to name or designate.

(Collins)

***[To tab](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tab)*** meaning  to name,  designate is from 1924, probably from tag:

> - "designate, label, name," 1924, earlier "affix a tab to" 1872 (implied in tabbed), perhaps an alteration of [tag](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tag&allowed_in_frame=0) (v.2).

Comment: That makes sense. But I think of it being used for objects, not selecting people for positions or jobs. As if you stuck a sticky note on their head.

Comment: @jabbermonkey - it is probably an extension of its usage.

Comment: The usage actually could come from sports, with a particular player having a tab added to his card/folder, or his card/folder being filed under a different "tab" in a filing cabinet, based on his skill set or playing position.

Comment: Honestly, I think it came about by people making a mistake. I have no evidence of course, just my idea.